# Solving the system $\sqrt{x/y}+\sqrt{y/z}+\sqrt{z/x}=\sqrt{y/x}+\sqrt{z/y}+\sqrt{x/z}=3$, $\sqrt{xyz}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am having problems solving this particular system of equations (SOE). The only thing I see that could be useful is the first and second equations are reciprocals of each other. I just don't know how I can use that information to help solve the SOE.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{x}}=3 \\
\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{y\:}{x\:}}+\sqrt{\frac{z\:}{y\:}}+\sqrt{\frac{x\:}{z\:}}=3 \\
\displaystyle\sqrt{xyz}=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Is there a way to solve this algebraically other than solving by inspection?
Thank you for any help/assistance you can provide!

Comment: Square bth sides of the last equation to get $x=\frac1{yz}$.  Now eliminate $x$ from the first two equations, and see what you can do from there.

Comment: A quick way of solving this problem is noticing that the first two lines are reciprocals of each other, in particular the unknowns. So you can make a substitution and rewrite the first two lines as $a+b+c=3$ and $a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}=3$. The important observation here is the constant $3$ is left unchanged even though the unknowns are reciprocals. That would mean the unknowns must be $1$ because there is no other real number whose multiplicative inverse is itself. The third line also confirms the unknowns are all equal to $1$.

Comment: Note that $-1$ is its own multiplicative inverse as well. However, I have shown that $-1$ doesn't work, though

Answer (score 4):

You can set $\sqrt{x/y}=a$, $\sqrt{y/z}=b$, $\sqrt{z/x}=c$, so the first two equations become
$$
a+b+c=3,\qquad \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3
$$
and also $abc=1$. Hence the second equation yields $ab+bc+ca=3$.

Therefore the three numbers are the roots of the polynomial $t^3-3t^2+3t-1$. Now you can finish, can't you?

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $x,y,z >0$ ,we have $$\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{x}} \geq 3$$ By the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), and it is given that it is **equal** to it's minimum value, and that happens only when all the terms are equal, that is, $$\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{z}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{x}}$$ We can see that now $x=y=z=1$ is the only solution possible in $\mathbb{R}$ which is satisfied by other equations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are looking for a generalization with RHS other than $3$ and $1$, this system of equations is solvable by inspection where $$x=y=z=1$$